# Replace rows in an array of lists with rows from matrix

Tags: r

I currently have an array of lists and a matrix that are produced with this code:

```
require(gtools)

FiveStates = array(list(NULL), c(32,2))

four.1 = combinations(5,4,c(LETTERS[1:5]))

four.2 = four.1[nrow(four.1):1,]
```

I'd like to replace rows 2-6 of the first column in the array FiveStates with all five rows in the matrix four.2 elementwise. How can I do this without having to replace each row separately?

Edit: I'd like to make FiveStates[2,1] show "B", "C", "D", "E"; FiveStates[3,1] show "A", "C", "D", "E"; and so on and so forth, so that the 2nd to 6th entries in the first column of FiveStates have vectors that match the rows of four.2[2:6,].

(Also, the package you need to use the combinations() function is now in the code. Sorry about that.)

Comment: What library does the function combinations come from?

Comment: What does it mean to replace a single column of `FiveStates` with the complete `four.2` matrix? Please clarify by showing the expected output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can replace blocks of a matrix that is populated with list using regular matrix  indexing:

```
FiveStates[2:6, 1] <- lapply(1:nrow(four.1), function(x) four.2[x, ] )
FiveStates[2:6, 1] 

[[1]]
[1] "B" "C" "D" "E"

[[2]]
[1] "A" "C" "D" "E"

[[3]]
[1] "A" "B" "D" "E"

[[4]]
[1] "A" "B" "C" "E"

[[5]]
[1] "A" "B" "C" "D"
```